# feature: **kwargs allowing improperly named variables

Tags: python, python-2.x

The following is invalid python:

```
def myInvalidFun(kw arg zero=6):
    pass
```

The following is valid python:

```
def myValidFun(**kwargs):
    if kwargs.has_key("kw arg zero"):
        pass
```

To call `myValidFun`, however, is tricky.  For instance, the next few approaches do not work:

```
myValidFun(kw arg zero=6)      # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
myValidFun("kw arg zero"=6)    # SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

kwargs = dict("kw arg zero"=6) # SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression 
myValidFun(**kwargs)
```

(Perhaps the identical errors to the last two hint at what happens under the hood?)  This, however, DOES work:

```
kwargs = {"kw arg zero": 6}
myValidFun(**kwargs)
```

Is there a reason why, in particular, `myValidFun("kw arg zero"=6)` is not valid, in light of the {:} syntax for creating dictionaries?

(More background: I have a class which is much like a dictionary, only with significant amounts of validation, and an `__init__` which builds a container using the entries of the dictionary, but is not a dictionary... it is actually an XML ElementTree, which is in some ways list-like and in others dict-like.  The `__init__` method must take keys like "my first element" and "my_first_element" and consider them different things.  The class and `__init__` work fine with **kwargs, but initializing my class is a multi-liner in the form of my example which does work, and seems like it could be simpler.)

edit: I understand the concept of identifiers, and my invalid code is there to make a point.  I guess my question should be rephrased as:

Why is the following valid?:

```
myValidFun(**{"invalid identifier":6})
```

Comment: Pass the data as a keyword argument: data={ ... } as space are not valid as parameter names.

Comment: This sounds like a safer idea.  I mean, I know the last valid snip works with my current python implementation, but it seems a little sketchy to me.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keywords to python functions must be valid identifiers.  This is because on the other side, they need to be unpacked into identifiers (variables):

```
def foo(arg=3):
    print arg
```

most of the things you have are not valid identifiers:

```
kw arg zero  #Not valid identifier -- Can't have spaces
"kw arg zero" #Not valid identifier -- It's parsed as a string (expression)
```

Doing

```
dict("kw arg zero" = 6)
```

is no different to the parser than

```
myValidFunc("kw arg zero" = 6)
```

---

now as you've pointed out, You *can* pass things view mapping packing/unpacking (`**kwargs`).  However, it can only be accessed through a dictionary.

Comment: Right, I get that, and while I didn't think about the case of dict() being a function that takes a **kwargs argument, that makes perfect sense now.  But then why is `myValidFunc(**{"kw arg zero":6})` valid?  The resulting dictionary created has a key which is not a valid identifier, right?  I still feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: @EthanCoon -- Yes, it's an invalid identifier, however, it can never be unpacked on the other side as an identifier, only as part of the `kwargs` dictionary.

Comment: @EthanCoon -- interestingly enough, I can't find anywhere in the specification where it actually states that this behavior is allowed.  The best I've found is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) which only talks about valid identifiers.  it's possible that this is implementation dependent behavior (but I'd need to search a bunch more to know for sure).

Comment: Hmm, ok.  "It's not in the spec and so is undefined behavior of the interpreter, so you just got lucky" is an ok answer by me.  I'll wait a little to see if there are other comments/answers, but if you edit something to that effect into your answer I'll give it the check.  Thanks!

Comment: @EthanCoon -- Well ... I'm going to be a little more careful than that here ... there's a difference between "I can't find it in the spec" and "It's not in the spec" :-P.

Comment: @EthanCoon: Dictionaries can have keys which are not valid identifiers; you just can't unpack them into variables. `myValidFunc(**{"kw arg zero":6})` works because behind the scenes, you're basically just passing a dictionary into a function. It *may* get unpacked into variables, in which case the keys *do* have to be valid identifiers, but if you never do that unpacking the interpreter won't bother checking.

Answer (score 0):

`myInvalidFun(kw arg zero=6):` is invalid because spaces are not allowed in [identifiers](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

`myValidFun("kw arg zero"=6)`  is invalid because functions expect the keywords to be valid variable names not strings. Some thing like `"kw arg zero"=6` is also invalid  because you can't assign a value to a string.

`dict("kw arg zero"=6)` : Same as above. BTW `dict()` accepts (key,value) pairs or an iterable.

This is valid because you only passed a dict here and dicts can strings as key with spaces.

```
def myValidFun(**kwargs): #using ** here simply packs the dictionary again
        pass
myValidFun(**{"invalid identifier":6})
```

This is valid because you used a valid identifier in function definition

```
def myValidFun( foo = 5):  #foo from dict replaces it's default value
    print foo               #prints 6
myValidFun(**{"foo":6})
```

Invalid:

```
def myValidFun(foo bar = 5): # syntax error, invalid identifier
    print foo
myValidFun(**{"foo bar":6})
```

Answer (score 0):

your key names cannot have spaces. 
by putting quotes around the argument in your function call, an expression is evaluated

try this

```
def myValidFun(**kwargs):
    if "kw_arg_zero" in kwargs:
        print kwargs["kw_arg_zero"]


myValidFun(kw_arg_zero="whatever")
```