# Are the keys of a kwargs argument to Python function guaranteed to be type string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

```
def func(**kwargs):
   for key, value in kwargs.items():
      # Is key always going to be a string?
      # Could it have spaces?
      pass
```

Two questions about kwargs in Python.

1. Is every key of kwargs guaranteed to be of type str?  If so, I can avoid type checking.
2. If #1 is true, would every key be guaranteed to not have spaces?

Comment: Related: [Why does python accept invalid names as keyword arguments when using **? - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/33fid7/why_does_python_accept_invalid_names_as_keyword/)

Comment: Just to be clear, the two questions I was concerned about was:
1) Will the key from kwargs be a str type?
2) Could the key from kwargs have spaces?

Comment: You could [edit] the question if you want

Comment: [`keywords must only contain strings and all keys must be unique.`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/cpython/abstract.h#L91) - `abstract.h` `_PyVectorcall_Function`

Comment: [PyArg_ValidateKeywordArguments(PyObject *kwargs)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ec70102066fe5534f1a62e8f496d2005e1697db/Python/getargs.c#L1604) ... `if (!_PyDict_HasOnlyStringKeys(kwargs)) {...`  - in getargs.c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A keyword argument passed directly must be a valid Python identifier, and yes it will always be treated as strings. Anything else is a `SyntaxError`.

```
f(foo=1) # Works
f($=1) # Fails
f(1=1) # Fails
```

Although, you can also give keyword arguments through unpacking. In this case, your keyword arguments must be strings still, but they can take any format.

Let's define a dummy function to test this.

```
def f(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
```

A keyword argument can contain a space or be a string of digits. It can even contain special characters.

```
f(**{"hello world": 'foo'}) # prints {'hello world': 'foo'}
f(**{"1": 'foo'}) # prints {'1': 'foo'}
f(**{"$": 'foo'}) # prints {'$': 'foo'}
```

A keyword argument must be a string. Anything else is a `TypeError`.

```
f(**{1: 'foo'}) # TypeError: f() keywords must be strings
f(**{b'foo': 1}) # TypeError: f() keywords must be strings
```

Comment: [Calls](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) in the Expressions section of the Language Reference talks about parameters being placed in slots - maybe these are `__slots__`?  [object.__slots__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__slots__) seems to implies strings only.

Comment: @wwii: No, I'm pretty sure the slots being referred to in that documentation is unrelated to `__slots__` except to the extent that they represent similar concepts who have ended up with the same names applied. The `__slots__` mechanic has to do with attributes of class instances, not with function calling.

Answer (score 3):

The `keywords` in `kwargs` should follow the rules of variable names, `full_name` is a valid variable name (and a valid `keyword`), `full name` is not a valid variable name (and not a valid `keyword`).

From [PEP 362 -- Function Signature Object](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/#parameter-object):

> A Parameter object has the following public attributes and methods:
>   **name : str**
>    - The name of the parameter as a string. Must be a valid python identifier name (with the exception of `POSITIONAL_ONLY` parameters, which can have it set to `None`.)

And, from the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers):

> **2.3. Identifiers and keywords:**
>   ...
>   Within the ASCII range (U+0001..U+007F), the valid characters for identifiers are the same as in Python 2.x: the uppercase and lowercase letters `A` through `Z`, the underscore `_` and, except for the first character, the digits `0` through `9`.
>   ...

Comment: Maybe as a reference to the official [python docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/#parameter-object) which says `The name of the parameter as a string. Must be a valid python identifier name`. And `Identifiers can be a combination of letters in lowercase (a to z) or uppercase (A to Z) or digits (0 to 9) or an underscore _` from [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keywords-identifier).

Comment: @OlivierMelançon that would be referring to the name `kwargs` here

Comment: @OlivierMelançon No. In function signatures and function calls, when an explicit keyword argument like `f(..., key=value)` is used, `key` must be a valid identifier name. But when a function is called using dict unpacking like you do, arbitrary strings can be used as keys.

Comment: Python allows the use of arbitrary dictionaries to be passed as **kwargs. I don't know why they would not verify the kwarg's name but throw a TypeError when using an int as keyword. This has been discussed in 2013 already - [feature: **kwargs allowing improperly named variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700006/feature-kwargs-allowing-improperly-named-variables)

Comment: Thanks makes sense but for kwargs in particular, spaces are allowed.  I'm clarifying my question slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already covered the practical side of this, but I wondered if the documentation actually made any guarantees about keyword dictionaries' types.

The [documentation on call semantics](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) does not specifically say keyword arguments will have type `str` in the dictionary.

This is all that the documentation says about the type of the value of keyword arguments passed to a parameter declared with `**`:

> a dictionary containing the excess keyword arguments (using the keywords as keys and the argument values as corresponding values), or a (new) empty dictionary

So, theoretically, it appears that the documentation allows you to recieve keyword arguments as `bytes`, but this does not occur in any current implementation of Python 3.

(For Python 2, the same holds, but for `unicode` instead of `bytes`.)