# how to give object to keyword argument as key

Tags: python, dictionary, object, keyword-argument

what I want to do is like this

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "james"

def foo(**kwargs):
    for obj, new_name in kwargs.items():
        obj.name = new_name

f = Foo()
foo(f="Tom")  # f have to be recognized as an object not a string "f"
```

as my knowledge, kwargs is a dictionary.

I tested giving an object as key in dictionary. and dictionary can have an object as key.

```
dd = {f: 12}
print(dd)

>>>
{<__main__.Foo object at 0x00D685D0>: 12}
```

but when I give an object to function's parameter as key, it becomes just string "f".

Is there the way that doesnt' ruin the original syntax

```
function(obj=value, obj2=value2, ...)
```

not like this

```
function((obj, value), (obj2, value2), ...)
    proper process to tuple
```

EDIT: use this code inside the function

```
    obj = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], f"{obj_name}")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it becomes just string?" To use a dict as kwargs you would need `func(**my_dict)`

Comment: @Heike I edited question. I need to pass an object Foo() by parameter. f=Foo(). when I do like function(f="Tom"), "f" is just string in the function. but I want f be the Foo() in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently we cannot have anything else other than strings as key type.

Check detailed answer here : [Are the keys of a kwargs argument to Python function guaranteed to be type string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897649/are-the-keys-of-a-kwargs-argument-to-python-function-guaranteed-to-be-type-strin)

Check source code here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ec70102066fe5534f1a62e8f496d2005e1697db/Python/getargs.c#L1604

Answer (score 0):

kwargs as being a dictionary that maps each keyword to the value that we pass alongside it. That is why when we iterate over the kwargs there doesn’t seem to be any order in which they were printed out.

```
def myFun(**kwargs):  
    for key, value in kwargs.items(): 
        print ("%s == %s" %(key, value)) 

# Driver code 
myFun(first ='Geeks', mid ='for', last='Geeks')
```

you can go for **args
The ** symbol is used before an argument to pass a keyword argument dictionary to a function, this syntax used to successfully run the code when we don’t know how many keyword arguments will be sent to the function.

```
# function definition 
def displayArgument(**arguments):  
    for arg in arguments.items(): 
        print(arg) 

# function call 
displayArgument(argument1 ="hello", argument2 = 4, 
                argument3 ="code")
```

Comment: there is no passing object as parameter in your answer only string or int values are passed. I need to pass object of Foo class by parameter

Comment: sorry for ambiguous question

Comment: u can pass the object of Foo class  in func foo as a parameter.