# If dict(a=1) is accepted then why not dict(1=1)?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have started learning Python 3 and came across dictionaries topic.

For example, dictionaries can be created using `dict` keyword, like:

```
>>> exp=dict(a=2,b=5,c=8)
>>> exp
{'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 8}
```

But, when I try the same with integers as keys, it is returning errors.

```
>>> exp=dict(1=2, 2=3)
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Then I tried just using curly braces, it worked fine

```
>>> exp = {1:2,2:3}
>>> exp
{1: 2, 2: 3}
```

May I know why is this happening?

Comment: You are essentially handing the `dict()` constructor keyword arguments. Keyword argument keys must be a valid python identifier. See this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57897711/12479639

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the `dict` constructor keyword arguments. A [keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-keyword-item) must be an [*identifier*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier) followed by an equals sign, then an [*expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression). However, you're supplying an integer instead of an identifier. Meanwhile, a dict literal (enclosed in curly braces) doesn't have this restriction.

Answer (score 2):

`1` and `2` are not valid keyword arguments. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) is the source.

You can either use `exp = {1:2,2:3}` as you already figured out yourself, or `exp=dict([(1, 2), (2, 3)])`.