# Why does unpacking non-identifier strings work on a function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've noticed, to my surprise, that in a function call, I could unpack a `dict` with strings *that weren't even valid python identifiers*.

It's surprising to me since argument names must be identifiers, so allowing a function call to unpack a `**kwargs` that has non-identifiers, with no run time error, doesn't seem healthy (since it could bury problems deeper that where they actually occur).

Unless there's an actual **use** to being able to do this, in which case my question becomes "what would that use be?".

### Example code

Consider this function:

```py
def foo(**kwargs):
    first_key, first_val = next(iter(kwargs.items()))
    print(f"{first_key=}, {first_val=}")
    return kwargs
```

This shows that, within a function call, you can't unpack a `dict` that has has integer keys, which is EXPECTED.

```py
>>> t = foo(**{1: 2, 3: 4})
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: foo() keywords must be strings
```

What is really not expected, and surprising, is that you can, on the other hand, unpack a `dict` with string keys, even if these are not valid python identifiers:

```py
>>> t = foo(**{'not an identifier': 1, '12': 12, ',(*&$)': 100})
first_key='not an identifier', first_val=1
>>> t
{'not an identifier': 1, '12': 12, ',(*&$)': 100}
```

Comment: the ** operator for unpacking dicts is supposed to have string keys. this is because keywords arguments ARE always strings.

Comment: I mention it already: That integers don't work is not surprising. What **is** surprising is that I **can** unpack **non-identifier** strings.

Comment: The only use case I can think of is - Unpacking and passing non-identifier strings in a dictionary as kwargs to a function/method would let us avoid methods like naming keywords as `class_`, `from_` and still be able to access keys with names `class` and `from` from a dictionary. The keys can be accessed from the method/instance `__dict__` easily, and so this would avoid taking the pain to remember where the underscores in such arguments need to be added, etc, etc

Comment: since we already know that you can't access a keyword passed through an unpacked dict into a function using identifiers, but necessarily need to be accessed using that dictionary, maybe the developers didn't feel a need to validate whether an unpacked dict being passed consists of valid identifier names.
I do not know the original intention behind this behaviour, though.

Comment: @a_n, but you don't need non-identifiers for that (if I understand your application correctly) (referring to your first comment).

Comment: @thorwhalen Lemme explain. I was referring to the tkinter module having strange alterations to its keyword arguments at places, such as using `class_` in widgets, and using `from_` in spinboxes, etc. so even though tkinter functions usually accept unpacked keyword args, u still have to remember those explicitly while creating a dictionary of keyword args (the dictionaries for specifying common style for multiple widgets usually)

Comment: Also, i can't think of any case where `**dictionary` doesn't end up in yet another dictionary.

Comment: I was actually speculating the methodology of how function calls probably store and pass around arguments internally, and my logic tells me that it's perfectly reasonable for it to allow such 'strange' keywords..
on a side note: try doing `while = 765` and `__builtins__.__dict__['while'] = 765` or `globals()['while'] = 765`.. the first one doesn't work, but the others do.. what's more, u can access those values using the same dictionaries, the same way u can access any others using the dict. this hints at something about how identifiers and their references might actually be stored internally

Comment: @thorwhalen It seems very unlikely that this behaviour serves a specific use case. It's probably just kept simple for efficiency. The `kwargs` cannot be unpacked *as actual identifiers*, so no real harm is done by allowing it.

Comment: @thorwhalen Also note that `kwargs` isn't the only context in which this sort of behaviour can occur. For example, this doesn't raise an exception: `class X: pass; x = X(); setattr(x, '42', 'spam'); vars(x)` => `{'42': 'spam'}`. However, `setattr` *will* raise an exception if a non-string is used, just as with `kwargs`. (PS: see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44689108/984421)).

Comment: @ekhumoro: Oh my, the plot thickens! In contrast with what you said, I would say if something has no use, I'd prefer that the language not allow it. Fail early and closer to the problem.

Comment: Of course, this will vary according to person and context, but when (like I do often) you're treating language constructs (say functions) as first-class citizens, passing functions and arguments around, catching such "errors" early can be valuable.

Comment: That said your efficiency argument, @ekhumoro, is the argument that is most convincing to me so far. I can see how such checks wouldn't be worth the overhead on average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is more of a `kwargs` issue than an unpacking issue. For example, one wouldn't run into the same issue with `foo`:

```
def foo(a, b):
    print(a + b)

foo(**{"a": 3, "b": 2})
# 5

foo(**{"a": 3, "b": 2, "c": 4})
# TypeError: foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'

foo(**{"a": 3, "b": 2, "not valid": 4})
# TypeError: foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'not valid'
```

But when `kwargs` is used, that flexibility comes with a price. It looks like the function first attempts to pop out and map all the named arguments and then passes the remaining items in a `dict` called `kwargs`. Since all keywords are strings (but all strings are not valid keywords), the first check is easy - `keywords must be strings`. Beyond that, it's up to the author to figure out what to do with remaining items in `kwargs`.

```
def bar(a, **kwargs):
    print(locals())
    
bar(a=2)
# {'a': 2, 'kwargs': {}}

bar(**{"a": 3, "b": 2})
# {'a': 3, 'kwargs': {'b': 2}}

bar(**{"a": 3, "b": 2, "c": 4})
# {'a': 3, 'kwargs': {'b': 2, 'c': 4}}

bar(**{1: 3, 3: 4})
# TypeError: keywords must be strings
```

Having said all that, there definitely is inconsistency but not a flaw. Some related discussions:

1. [Supporting (or not) invalid identifiers in **kwargs](https://discuss.python.org/t/supporting-or-not-invalid-identifiers-in-kwargs/17147)
2. [feature: **kwargs allowing improperly named variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16700006/7128934)