# When unpacking a dictionary in a call to a function using ** why must the keywords be string type?

Tags: python

```
def Fn(**kwargs):
     print("dict = ",kwargs)
     

d = {'a':5,'b':7}
Fn(**d)
# Output    dict =  {'a': 5, 'b': 7}



d = {1:5,('a','s'):7}
Fn(**d)
# TypeError: Fn() keywords must be strings
```

What is the reason for the above error?

Comment: Please use the code formatting button next time. And please add a tag that tells us which programming language this is supposed to be!

Comment: Because the names of parameters also have to be valid variable names... What else??

Comment: @ThierryLathuille they don't actually have to be representing valid identifiers, _just_ strings. `Fn(**{"hello world": 123})` would work, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, I had never noticed that. We even have [a question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700006/feature-kwargs-allowing-improperly-named-variables), and there is [a discussion about it](https://discuss.python.org/t/supporting-or-not-invalid-identifiers-in-kwargs/17147) on a Python discussion list.